# What to code in Dockerfile and docker-compose to pass local package

Tags: docker, go, module, docker-compose, dockerfile

I introduced local package with `go modules` for server side api. It works fine in local environment without error by commanding `go run main.go`.

But it does not work when commanding `docker-compose up`.

I want to know how to fix `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.

I command `go mod init` at `article` directory.

As result, it sets `module github.com/jpskgc/article` in go.mod.

```
article
  ├ db
  ├ client
  ├ api
  │  ├ main.go
  │  ├ controller
  │  │    └ controller.go
  │  └ Dockerfile
  ├ nginx
  ├ docker-compose.yml
  ├ go.mod
  └ go.sum
```

main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "os"
    "time"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller"
)
    api := router.Group("/api")
    {
        api.GET("/articles", func(c *gin.Context) {
            controller.GetArticleController(c, db)
        })
    }
    router.Run(":2345")
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest
ENV GO111MODULE=on
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/api"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - MYSQL_USER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_HOST
      - GO111MODULE
```

go.mod

```
module github.com/jpskgc/article

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.23.7
    github.com/gin-contrib/cors v1.3.0
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.4.0
    github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.4.1
    github.com/google/uuid v1.1.1
    github.com/joho/godotenv v1.3.0
)
```

I expect server side api working fine without error in docker environment. But the actual is that docker environment for server side fails to run.

Here is error message when commanding `docker-compose up`

```
api_1     | main.go:14:2: cannot find package "github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller" in any of:
api_1     |     /usr/local/go/src/github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller (from $GOROOT)
api_1     |     /go/src/github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller (from $GOPATH)
```

[Here](https://github.com/jpskgc/article/tree/try-golang-mod) is the entire source code on github (branch: try-golang-mod).

Answer (score 0):

This error message seems to indicate that Go modules are not enabled:

> Here is error message when commanding docker-compose up

```
api_1     | main.go:14:2: cannot find package "github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller" in any of:
api_1     |     /usr/local/go/src/github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller (from $GOROOT)
api_1     |     /go/src/github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller (from $GOPATH)
```

I would double check that the `GO111MODULE=on` environment variable  is being set and propagated properly.

There are some other things you could check here:

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#what-are-some-general-things-i-can-spot-check-if-i-am-seeing-a-problem

Comment: >GO111MODULE=on environment variable is being set and propagated properly. Yes, it was not set. but after setting and `docker-compose up`, there is another error message.

Comment: `api_1 | build command-line-arguments: cannot load github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller: cannot find module providing package github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller`

Comment: Thanks for notice. Yes it's just misspelling in this question. There is no typo-miss on github and local source code.

Comment: What exact 'go' command generated the error that started 'build command-line-arguments'?  When you're outside of any module and in module mode, you sometimes get 'command-line-arguments' as the package name and module name, which makes me still wonder if (a) you are setting the GO111MODULE=on environment variable properly and propagating it, and (b) whether you are inside of directory tree containing a valid go.mod file.

In general, things seem like they might be out of sync between the question, the error messages you supplied in the comments, and the repo.

Answer (score 0):

looks like PATH issue try this Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest
ENV GO111MODULE=on
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/user/myProject/app
COPY . .
RUN go mod download
RUN go build
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/src/github.com/user/myProject/app/api"]
```

*Set Volume* in compose file to:

```
./api:/go/src/github.com/user/myProject/app
```

***not tested, actual results may vary, but hopefully helps***

Comment: Thanks for advice. But unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: `api_1     | build command-line-arguments: cannot load github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller: cannot find module providing package github.com/jpskgc/article/api/controller`